# Unable to correctly solve ODE with Scilab

Tags: ode, scilab

I want to solve the following differential equation using scilab:

```
f(x)=sin(x);
```

with initial values as x0=0, y0=0;

What I have tried is this:

```
// Define x
x0=0; y0=0;
xinc=0.001; xf=6; x=x0:xinc:xf;

// Define differential equation
deff('y=f(x)','y=sin(x)');
// Solve differential equation

ydiff=ode(y0,x0,x,y);
```

However, I get error:

```
-->exec('C:\Users\Saaama\Desktop\sinx().sce', -1)
ydiff=ode(y0,x0,x,y);
                    !--error 4 
Undefined variable: y
at line       9 of exec file called by :    
exec('C:\Users\Saima\Desktop\sinx().sce', -1)
```

I have also tried

```
ydiff=ode(y0,x0,x,f);
```

Still I get the same error on ode function.

Answer (score 2):

`ode` expects a function that takes parameters time and space, `dotx=f(t,x)`, even if the time is not used in the function.

But from context you intent `x` to be the time variable, so that the problem is a simple quadrature. Then you need to use

```
deff('doty=f(x,y)','doty=sin(x)');
```

or the long form

```
function doty=f(x,y)
    doty=sin(x)
endfunction
```